# How to disable dialog box prompting to pick an app for "ms-gamingoverlay link"

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10 I am getting a dialog prompting me to pick an app (but without choices) for some "ms-gamingoverlay link".

The wording of the dialog box is:

> You'll need a new app to open this ms-gamingoverlay link
>
> [ ] Always use this app
>
> OK

Here is how it looks:

[image: Dialog box in question when starting Starcraft 2]

No matter whether I check the checkbox or dismiss the dialog box with <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the dialog box reappears next time I start a game (noticed this with a number of games, notably Starcraft 2 and Diablo 3).

Dismissing the dialog box with <kbd>Esc</kbd> causes a switch back to the desktop and only after selecting the game from the taskbar will I be able to start playing.

How do I get rid of this prompt altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all likelihood this was caused by removing one of the gaming-related apps that come with a stock Windows 10. You may have used [W10Privacy](https://www.winprivacy.de/english-home/), [BCUninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com) or even just PowerShell to remove such app. For example in W10Privacy the respective settings (in the *User-Apps* tab) look like this:

[image: User-Apps tab in W10Privacy]

Very likely uninstalling one (or all) of these items (as I did) cause the symptom with the prompt.

The *Game bar settings* allow us to get rid of the dialog:

[image: Game bar settings]

Obviously by uninstalling the app in the first place, this means you can't use the *Game bar* features.

The *Game bar settings* page can be found by finding the *Gaming* settings, then selecting the *Game bar* settings.

[image: Game bar settings inside Gaming settings]

There simply turn off the setting named "Record game clips, screenshots, and broadcast using Game bar".

As far as I can tell this will affect many games, although I only encountered this with Starcraft 2 and Diablo 3.